# How to reconfigure an existing IBM MQ Queue Manager to require username and password authentication?

Tags: authentication, ibm-mq

I've been testing a couple different applications that connect to an IBM MQ instance (Version 9.1.4.0), for the sole purpose of putting/retrieving messages to a collection of queues... no control over queue configuration, starting/stopping, etc. are needed.  My testing to this point has used an SSL connection with exchanged certificates as the only authentication method.  All that is working; I have the key/trust certificates on each side set up and confirmed they validate each other as expected.

Now, I need to test the feature where these applications supply an MQ User and Password as an additional authentication.  The apps have the necessary configuration settings & functionality to supply these; that's not the problem.  The problem is I can't work out how to reconfigure the Queue Manager I've been using to require User+PW authentication.  I know my efforts to this point (details to follow) have not been successful because the apps still connect successfully even when the MQ User & PW entries are blank.

What I tried initially was based on [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=roles-configuring-basic-registry-mq-console-rest-api) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=roles-mq-console-rest-api) documentation.  I edited the `mqwebuser.xml` file in my installation's data path (`C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\web\installations\Installation1\servers\mqweb`), and inserted the following elements:

```
<!-- 
Roles for the MQ Console 
-->
<enterpriseApplication id="com.ibm.mq.console">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="MQWebAdmin">
            <group name="MQWebAdminGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MQWebAdminRO">
            <group name="MQWebAdminROGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MQWebUser">
            <group name="MQWebUserGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MFTWebAdmin">
            <group name="MFTWebAdminGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MFTWebAdminRO">
            <group name="MFTWebAdminROGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</enterpriseApplication>

<!-- 
Roles for the MQ REST API 
-->
<enterpriseApplication id="com.ibm.mq.rest">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="MQWebAdmin">
            <group name="MQWebAdminGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MQWebAdminRO">
            <group name="MQWebAdminROGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MQWebUser">
            <group name="MQWebUserGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MFTWebAdmin">
            <group name="MFTWebAdminGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="MFTWebAdminRO">
            <group name="MFTWebAdminROGroup" realm="defaultRealm"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</enterpriseApplication>

<!-- 
Sample Basic Registry 
-->
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="defaultRealm">
    <user name="mqadmin" password="luggage12345"/>
    <user name="mqsubadmin" password="luggage12345"/>
    <user name="mqdatauser" password="luggage12345"/>
    <group name="MQWebAdminGroup">
       <member name="mqadmin"/>
    </group>
    <group name="MQWebAdminROGroup">
       <member name="mqsubadmin"/>
    </group>
    <group name="MFTWebAdminGroup">
       <member name="mqadmin"/>
    </group>
    <group name="MFTWebAdminROGroup">
       <member name="mqsubadmin"/>
    </group>
    <group name="MQWebUserGroup">
       <member name="mqadmin"/>
       <member name="mqdatauser"/>
    </group>
</basicRegistry>
```

Then, I opened the Queue Manager in the MQ Explorer app, right-clicking on it and selecting Connection Details > Properties.  I selected the "Userid" tab, checked the option "Enable user identification", and entered the Userid "mqdatauser".  I also clicked the radiobutton to "Prompt for password."

Finally, I rebooted the server hosting IBM MQ to ensure any cached values would be reloaded and refreshed.

After doing these steps though -- as I mentioned above -- the apps I'm testing both connect normally to MQ and can push/pull data from the queues under this queue manager, even though their MQ User & PW configurations are both blank.  So obviously I haven't finished the job of configuring things to require Userid+PW authentication for access to the queues under that Queue Manager.

What steps did I miss?

Comment: Both links your provided are related to the MQ Console and REST API, both are accessed over HTTP not the MQ protocol that you are trying to use with MQ Explorer.

Comment: This is the site you can review for instructions: [https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=authentication-connection-configuration](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=authentication-connection-configuration)

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, this helps a lot.  So the only options mentioned in the article are IDPWOS (validate login to local OS) and IDPWLDAP (validate login to LDAP server).  Am I right this means there's no way to validate against users/passwords provided in the `<basicRegistry>` element?

Comment: I don't know what `<basicRegistry>` means.   The user needs to be either in the local /etc/passwd or configured via PAM (for Unix/Linux) or for windows a local user or AD user.  Or in LDAP.

Comment: Per the OP, `<basicRegistry>` is an XML element the `mqwebuser.xml` file used by MQ.  But your comment answers my question, the user+pw must be authenticated by some resource (OS, LDAP) outside of MQ itself.

Comment: mqwebuser.xml is only related to the web console and REST API, not the underlying MQ queue manager.